# Force a python function to have a definite signature with `inspect.Parameter` and `inspect.Signature` API's

Tags: python, functional-programming, signature

I wolud like to mimic the following signature and check if a functions follow that signature:

```
def simple_output_patch_predictor(patch: torch.Tensor,model: nn.Module,) -> torch.Tensor:
    ...
```

When I call `inspect.signature` I get:

```
<Signature (patch: torch.Tensor, model: torch.nn.modules.module.Module) -> torch.Tensor>
```

Is it possible to mimic that signatura from scratch without using `from_callable`. I want to force a function to follow the signature `<Signature (patch: torch.Tensor, model: torch.nn.modules.module.Module) -> torch.Tensor>`.